# Matrix product equals O

Tags: matrices, quadratics

I'm stuck in this question :

\begin{bmatrix}
x & 4 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 2\\ 
0 & 2 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
4\\
1 
\end{bmatrix}

The product of the above 3 matrices equals O.
The result of the product comes out to be :

\begin{bmatrix}
2x^2+4x & 4x-8 & -4
\end{bmatrix}

Since this is equal to O, which is a null matrix, I did:

2x^2 + 4x = 0

4x - 8 = 0

However this cannot be possible as -4=!0

What am I doing wrong here?

The correct option seems to be: x = -2  +- \sqrt{10}

Comment: The result is a scalar (or a $1\times 1$ matrix depending on how you want to think about it), not a $1\times 3$ matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bye_World, thanks for the answer.

I had a brain malfunction I suppose.

[1x3] * [3x1] is a [1x1] matrix

Hence, the result is 2x^2 + 8x -4 = 0